# how to change name of all html input field with name + increment in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have many HTML `input` text fields in my page with same class. All fields are dynamic generated, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="student_a" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_b" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_c" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_d" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_e" class="students" />
```

i want to change name of all input field with the help of class in Jquery
wanted result

```
<input type="text" name="student_1" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_2" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_3" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_4" class="students" />
<input type="text" name="student_5" class="students" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a function to the `attr()` method to achieve this:

```
$('.students').attr('name', function(i) {
    return 'student_' + (i + 1);
});
```

Comment: but numbering is staring from 0 how to set it from 1 ?

Comment: You can add 1 to `i`. Updated the answer for you.